# "Lock" Rotation of camera within interval

Tags: javascript, three.js, virtual-reality

I am using THREE.js for a VR game and I would like to lock the rotation of the camera on the y-axis between two angles. I don't want the user to see behind them but instead look left and right. I'm not sure how the coordinate system works for the camera, but here is a picture of what I want.

[image]

I'm using [threeVR](https://github.com/richtr/threeVR) which does not have max and min settings so I'm resorting to manually locking my camera's rotation in the `update` function of my program, but I don't know how.

Comment: In the threeVR api there's rotatestart, rotateend events - could possibly set your min and max values on rotatestart

Comment: @Neil which API, THREE.PerspectiveCamera? Thanks

Comment: I think you may need to dig into the library. Looking at the code, it updates on device orientation xyz, so I would personally look at adding a function in the library yourself to do constraints and issue a pull request if you like it

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just lock the angle with a min/max in the update loop?

```
camera.rotation.y = Math.max(startAngle, Math.min(endAngle, camera.rotation.y));
```

Comment: The library can read a device accelerometer. Would need testing with that to see if it jumps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't do what's expected. The camera sort of contorts in different directions when it hits a limit.